# How do I get Amazon Alexa (Echo) to run automations in Nexia?

Tags: smart-home, alexa, amazon-echo

I have an Amazon Alexa and have a Nexia bridge which manages devices throughout my home. I have the two connected via the Nexia skill in the Alexa app. I can do things like *"Alexa, turn the downstairs thermostat up 2 degrees"* and it works as expected.

However, I have automation skills in my Nexia account that I can't figure out how to activate. My automation I want to run is called "Energy Saver" and it should set both thermostats to *Energy Save* mode when activated.

[image: Nexia Configuration]

I've tried:

- Alexa, run Energy Saver
- Alexa, run Energy Saver on Nexia
- Alexa, ask Nexia to run Energy Saver
- etc.

I can't seem to figure out which command to tell Alexa that will translate to Nexia running the expected automation.

Comment: The key is to make sure that the “scenes” are discovered in the Alexa app, different than devices.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your skill supports scenes then they are enabled with on/off verbs, so it would be

> Alexa, turn on Energy Saver

You can check to see if scenes are supported if they have been discovered and shown in the Alexa mobile app